# Detect highest order of derivative in expression?

Tags: pattern-matching

Is it possible to detect the highest order (or generally all orders) of derivatives in an expression?

Consider

```
eqn = D[a[x,t],t] == D[a[x,t],x,x]
```

How would I go about detecting that the highest order of the partial derivative in x is 2 in eqn?

I was thinking of using MatchQ, however this

```
MatchQ[Derivative[2, 0][a][x, t], eqn]
```

just returns False.

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this:

```
Cases[eqn, Derivative[orders__] -> {orders}, Infinity, Heads -> True]

(* Out: {{0, 1}, {2, 0}} *)
```

Now, you've got the orders of each derivative returned in a list that you can manipulate as you please.

Comment: Terrific thank you so much!