# question about using Heads->True in Cases command

Tags: pattern-matching, core-language, head

I was trying to find the order of highest derivative of expression. Using solution given in [detect-highest-order-of-derivative-in-expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18967/detect-highest-order-of-derivative-in-expression)

I just do not understand why when removing `Heads->True` then `Cases` do not work.

Here is example. I want to find the order of all derivatives (then I can use `Max` to find the largest)

```
ClearAll[y,x,n]
expr=y''[x]+y'[x]+x+y[x] Sin[x];
Cases[expr,Derivative[n_]->n,Infinity,Heads->True]
(*  {1,2} *)
```

but

```
 Cases[expr,Derivative[n_]->n,Infinity]
 (* {} *)
```

From help `ref/Cases`  it just says that this option will just include the `Head` in the result:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I do not see how and why this will made `Cases` find the pattern. I do not even see the `Head` returned back in the result.  May the above documentation should say more about this.

What is the rule of the thumb as to when to use `Heads->True` in Cases? Since this seems to be very critical in making it work in this example, and I do not want to just try each time to see if it works or not.

Comment: `y''[x] // FullForm` gives `Derivative[2][y][x]`. That `Derivative` term is in the `Head`. You'll could get away with `Heads->False` here by doing `Derivative[n_][_][__]`, but note that this may not work in general.

Comment: @b3m2a1 thanks. I know this. But I do not see how this made Cases work. Help says that `Head->True` just makes `Cases` also return the Head in the  result. So I would have expected something like `{Derivative,1,2}` to be returned.

Comment: Nah, `Heads->True` makes it  (try to) *match* the `Head` too. The docs were just noting that since it was matching the `_Symbol`, it was going to return the `Head`.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Ok, but that is not what documentation says :). Mathematica helps sometimes is not really clear and very short in explaining things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `Cases` searches an expression, it assumes by default `Heads -> False`.  This means that expression heads are not searched for matches.  With `Heads -> True`, heads are searched.

By means of the visualization helper function `frameMatches` (defined at the bottom of this post), we can explore the implications of this option.

First, let's look at the full form of the expression in question:

```
expr // FullForm
```

[image: fullform of expression]

Now, let's highlight all of the subexpressions (i.e. anything that matches `_`), but ignoring heads:

```
frameMatches[expr, _, Infinity, Heads -> False]
```

[image: all subexpressions, ignoring heads]

This is the full set of possible matches for an unrestricted pattern.  Note that `Derivative[1]`, `Derivative[2]`, `Derivative[1][y]`, `Derivative[2][y]` and the other heads are *not* in this set -- even though the expressions that contain them are.  So it is no surprise that it we try to match the pattern `Derivative[_]` we come up empty:

```
frameMatches[expr, Derivative[_], Infinity, Heads -> False]
```

[image: fullform of expression]

```
Cases[expr, Derivative[_], Infinity, Heads -> False]
(* {} *)
```

Now, let's include heads when matching.  Again, with the unrestricted pattern `_`:

```
frameMatches[expr, _, Infinity, Heads -> True]
```

[image: all subexpressions, including heads]

This time around, `Derivative[1]` and `Derivative[2]` are included in the search.  And the search even descends into the heads of those expressions, to include `Derivative`.

This is why we now get the results we want using the desired pattern:

```
frameMatches[expr, Derivative[_], Infinity, Heads -> True]
```

[image: matched Derivative forms]

```
Cases[expr, Derivative[_], Infinity, Heads -> True]
(* {Derivative[1], Derivative[2]} *)
```

**Matching Heads with *Heads -> False***

Incidentally, the option *Heads -> True* is not the only way to match heads within an expression.  We can write explicit patterns that will extract the heads from matched non-head parts.  For example:

```
Cases[expr, (d : Derivative[_])[_][_] :> d, Infinity]
(* {Derivative[1], Derivative[2]} *)
```

**Is All This Documented?**

Yes, but as usual it is terse.  The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Heads.html) for `Heads` says:

> `Heads` is an option for functions which use level specifications that specifies whether heads of expressions should be included.
>
> `Heads->True` treats heads just like other elements of expressions for the purpose of levels.
>
> `Heads->False` never includes heads as part of any level of an expression.

---

**frameMatches**

*caveat: this function works for the examples at hand, but is not intended to be fully general*

```
frameMatches[expr_, patt_, args___] :=
  Replace[expr // FullForm, e:patt :> Framed[e], args] // expandFrames

expandFrames[e_] :=
  MakeBoxes[e] //
  Replace[#, RowBox[{"Framed", "[", x_, "]"}] :> FrameBox[x], Infinity]& //
  Replace[RowBox[{FrameBox["FullForm", ___],"[", x_, "]"}] :> x] //
  RawBoxes
```